# Column segregation using datatype as parameter

Tags: sql, types, numbers, varchar2

I want to know if there is a method in which we can select the columns of a table of a specific datatype in a table that has columns of various datatypes. Say a table has three columns - `SSN`, `Name` and `phone number` where `SSN` and `Name` are of `Varchar2` and `phone number` is of `number` datatype, can I extract only the columns that has its datatype as `varchar2`(`SSN` and `Name`)?

Comment: What database engine is that? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following can be the solution :

select Column_Name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where Table_Name = 'Tablename' and DATA_TYPE='Varchar'

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly then this should work.

```
select * from TABLE_NAME
where DATA_TYPE = 'Varchar2';
```

Comment: Im sorry E_McAndrew but the query did not worked. I have got the answer for it. And thank you so much for your help. Appreciate it :)